# How to define our own show and return particular anything for all values in haskell

Tags: function, haskell, module, functional-programming, functor

My problem:

To define a new data type called Locker that boxes values up with a key and i need to export two functions, lock and unlock. After that I wanted to define my own show (it should just return "*SECRET*" for all values), also locker should be instance of functor.
lock takes a key and a value and returns a Locker
unlock takes a key and a Locker and returns a Maybe, returning the value only if the key
matches.

My try:

```hs
import Lock

main = do
    print(Lock.lock)
    print(Lock.unlock)
```

```hs
module Lock

class Locker f where 

    lock :: (key -> value) -> f key -> f value
    if lock in sec
        then print("secret")
    else print("nothing")
    
    unlock :: (key -> locker) -> f key -> locker
```

Error:
parse error on input ‘class’

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a very common misunderstanding: a `class` in Haskell is not a OO-class it's more like an OO-interface.

I guess you want something like this:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
module Main where

main = do
    let locked = lock "1234" "Hello world"
    print locked
    print $ unlock "1234" locked
    print $ unlock "1111" locked


data Locker k v = Locker k v
deriving instance Functor (Locker k)

instance Show v => Show (Locker k v) where
  show (Locker _ _) = "Locker 'SECRET' 'SECRET'"

lock :: k -> v -> Locker k v
lock key value = Locker key value

unlock :: Eq k => k -> Locker k v -> Maybe v
unlock key (Locker actualKey v)
  | actualKey == key = Just v
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

this will output

```
Locker 'SECRET' 'SECRET'
Just "Hello world"
Nothing
```

---

Some explanation:

I did not use an extra module as I wanted to check if this works quickly - just move the part from `data Locker ..` into your module - if you only export `Locker` (not `Locker(..)`) from it users have to use `lock` (as a smart-constructor) to create `Locker`-values.

`data Locker k v = Locker k v` creates a new type named `Locker` - it is parametrized by two type-parameters: `k` for your key-type and `v` for your value-type.

It might be a bit confusing but the `Locker` after the `=` is a `data-constructor` - it's usually named like the type but if you like you can call it `MkLocker` too - here it takes two value-arguments - one of type `k` and one of type `v` for your key and value.

`derving instance Functor` generates a functor instance (don't know why you want it, but here you go) - for this you need the two `{-# LANGUAGE ... #-}` extensions.

next is the instance for `Show` - so that `show` works (`print` uses `show`!)

`lock` is basically just a call to the data-constructor `Locker`

`unlock` checks the key with a guard (the `| actualKey == key = ..` part) - for this it needs the key-type to be an instance of the `Eq`-class (see *class* ;) ) - you need this as `==` is *working* only on those (`==` **is defined** in `Eq`)

Comment: Thank you so much, but how can I return secret to all the values

Comment: I don't know what you mean with that - you want to *print*  the secret?

Comment: Yes sir , I need to define my own show and it should return"*secret*"for all values

Comment: this here does - it's a bit useless I guess - it's the first output in the example

Comment: Locker type
define a new data type called Locker that boxes values up with a key.
You should define Locker in its own module.
You should only export two functions, lock and unlock.
You will need to define your own show (it should just return "*SECRET*" for all values)
You need to make Locker be an instance of Functor
lock takes a key and a value and returns a Locker
unlock takes a key and a Locker and returns a Maybe, returning the value only if the key
matches.
You can require the key to be an Int

Comment: this is the complete question sir

Comment: so this is homework? (I don't care but my answers change based on that) - I think I solved your homework here - maybe it's more general than need be (*You can require the key to be an `Int`* might mean that you could define `data Locker v = Locker Int v` instead - you don't need the `Eq` constraint then as `Int` is an instance)

Comment: May I suggest you take this and try to solve the rest yourself?

Comment: OK sir I'll try to solve the rest.

Comment: PS: you are probably expected to implement the `Functor` instance yourself (not let GHC do it for you) - so better change the `derive instance Functor` with something similar to the `Show` instance here ... you'll want to implement `map :: (a -> b) -> Locker k a -> Locker k b` instead of `show :: Locker k v -> String` of cours

Comment: PPS: to give you some insight: I think your Prof. wants you to not do `deriving (Show)` as you probably saw in lecture as this will publish your *secret* do anyone doing `show myLockerValue` - in my example that would print `Locker "1234" "Hello world"` - I don't think it's too important what you show actually - I'd go with `"got U ... no cheating please"` ;)

Comment: Why do i often get parse error on input data , please help me with this , I'm bit confused as I'm new to this language

Comment: I don't think I can answer this question - you have to give some more information about the error and input causing it. But if you really want to learn you should take some time and try to figure it out yourself.